# Using same class in two very different contexts in LESS?

Tags: css, less

Let's say I have a class named `city-toggler`.

I currently have the class in here:

```
#city {
    .city-header {
        .box {
            .city-toggler {
                //styles here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I need to add a `city-toggler` element to a completely unrelated place in the website, for example:

```
.footer-holder -> .footer -> .footer-section -> .city-toggler
```

How do I do this in LESS without copying all the styles from above?

I suppose I could take `city-toggler` out of the LESS structure and use it separately, but is there a better solution?

Comment: LESS is not really my thing, but surely you would define the styles in a mixin, and then use the mixin in both places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing bad about defining the `city-toggler` context-independent if it is not dependend on a specific context. You don't have to copy any code.

Either do this:

```
.city-toggler {
  /* all styles of a default city-toggler */
}

#city {
  /* ... */
  .city-toggler {
    /* overrides that apply only to city-togglers in this context */
  }
}

#footer {
  /* same as for #city */
}
```

or, to not copy the code (not even in the compiled CSS, e.g. via mixins) but to prevent the city-toggler to be used in any context, do this:

```
#city, #footer {
  .city-toggler {
    /* all styles of a default city-toggler */
  }
}

#city {
  /* ... */
  .city-toggler {
    /* overrides that apply only to city-togglers in this context */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mixins should work for you:

```
   .my-mixin{
      background-color:#FFF;
   }
   #city {
    .city-header {
        .box {
            .city-toggler {
                .my-mixin;
            }
        }
    }
    .otherplace {
      .city-toggle {
        .my-mixin;
      }
    }
}
```